# jQuery line function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a `TypeError: $(...).data(...)` in this line `$(this).before($(this).data('daw_preguntaes').replace(regexp, time));}`. I am using Railscast 196, but this function don't load the new fields i want to show. I don't know what to put in the `data(fields)`

```
jQuery ->
        $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
        time = new Date().getTime()
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'),'g')
        $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp,time))
        event.defaultPrevented()
```

Survay View

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'questions_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_fields "New question",f,:questions  %>
```

Question View

```
<fieldset>
    <%= f.label :content, 'Question' %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
    <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
    <%= f.label :_destroy, "Delete" %>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It's likely because the data item `daw_preguntaes` (or `fields`, depending on what part of your question I read...) hasn't been set... can you update the question to include the part where it is being set?

Answer (score 0):

In RailsCasts #403, Ryan use an edit code in the CoffeeScript file. And I name the _question_fields I put _questions_fields

CoffeeScript

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .remove_fields', (event) ->
  $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
  $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
  event.preventDefault()

$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

Helper

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
        render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name,'#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n","")}) 
end
```